# Meta description dinamica

Tags: php, laravel, seo

Hola estoy teniendo dificultad para implementar la variable Categoria_row para que genere una meta description variable segun a que categoría pertenezca la pagina. Esto se puede solucionar de alguna forma o tengo que crear una pagina especifica para cada categoria? Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

```
@section('description', "$categoria_row->categoria")

<header class="page_header__header">
      <div class="container">

      <?php
            $titulo_pagina = "Búsqueda de Artículos:";

            if($categoria_busqueda > 0)
            {
              $categoria_row = \App\Categoria::find($categoria_busqueda);

              if($categoria_row)
              {
                $titulo_pagina = "Búsqueda de ".$categoria_row->categoria;

                if($subcategoria_busqueda > 0)
                {
                  $subcategoria_row = \App\Subcategoria::find($subcategoria_busqueda);

                  if($subcategoria_row)
                  {
                    $titulo_pagina = "Búsqueda de ".$subcategoria_row->subcategoria;
                  }
                }
              }
            }


          ?>

        <h1 class="page_header__title">{{$titulo_pagina}}</h1>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes quitarle las comillas simples:

Acabo de probarlo con un proyecto que tengo en Laravel y si funciona!!

Vista admin:

```
@php
$contenido = 'Borrar ADM V2';
@endphp
<!-- secciones para poner texto especifico -->
@section('titulo', $contenido)
```

Vista plantilla:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="{{ url('/admin-index') }}">Inicio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item active">@yield('titulo')</li>
</ol>
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]